# Acer Aspire One 756 with Pentium B967

Tags: hardware, laptop

Will ubuntu work on the Acer Aspire One 756 with the Pentium B967 processor, and if so, what version should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu should work for your computer. It's hard to say for sure until you have tried it, but I can't think of any reason why it would not work. I would say to try 12.04 if you can. I am assuming that this computer is a netbook from the information I have seen about it online. As such, you may have to use the Ubuntu alternate text-based installer. You can find this on their website. 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

For more specifics on whether or not this will work on your laptop, here's a link to a forum talking about it:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2041487

I hope this helped you. I hope Ubuntu works on your laptop.