# Cannot install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire One 756 (Intel Dual Core 847, 2 GB RAM)

Tags: system-installation, acer, usb-installation, ubuntu-netbook

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu (12.04) on a new Acer Aspire One 756 Netbook with Intel Dual Core 847, 2 GB RAM, and Linpus Linux pre-installed.

I have created a bootable USB Stick with Ubuntu 12.04 (which works fine for my desktop machine) with Pen Drive Linux. However, I am not able to boot from that USB stick.

I am aware of [a similar case](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196831/acer-aspire-one-756-with-pentium-b967), however the solution there -- switch boot mode to "Legacy" in BIOS -- does not work for me because there simply is no adjustable "Boot mode" in the BIOS. Yes, I really tried hard to spot it! I can change the boot order so that it has my USB stick on the top of the list, but it won't boot from the USB stick anyway.

Comment: When you try to boot from the USB, does it give you some error such as something related to **Secure boot** or **signature error**? That may be due to UEFI if it's new hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did not get any error message. It just went straight to the linpus linux which is installed on the hard disk.

Comment: I tried a variety of (mostly older) USB sticks and failed. Then I did the same with Ubuntu 12.10. With two USB sticks I failed again, but the third one worked and I got through the installation. Dunno if it's 12.10 instead of 12.04 or if it was just the right choice of USB stick...

Answer (score 2):

I have an Acer Aspire One 756 Windows 8 preinstalled and UEFI secure mode ON and I solved this problem.

1. Download an Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit version
2. Create a bootable USB with that Linux
3. Go to BIOS (press <kbd>F2</kbd> to startup) and set a supervisor password 
   doing so many menu options below will unlock
4. Set USB HDD first boot and disable secure mode
5. Reboot Linux and select try Linux (NO INSTALL)
6. Start GParted and use that to shrink Windows 8 partition (the most large one) to 20 gb
7. Into the free space created, create a 15 gb EXT4 partition and a 512 MG swap
8. Then start Linux installation and use OTHER option
9. Choose the new ext4 partition as / mount point and flag it to be formatted
10. DON'T touch grub installation partition. It should be `/dev/sda`. Leave it alone !!
11. Continue installing normally then reboot
12. Windows 8 will boot up DON'T worry !! This is normal and is a check to see if win 8 is there !!
13. Reboot Windows 8 and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS at startup

    - re enable secure mode !!
14. Go to security menu and use "add uefi executable as secure for boot" option
    here you will see  many folders , go to ubuntu an chose the ubuntu uefi file
15. BIOS now asks to add it as secure boot uefi firmware into database  and to set up a new name for it (set ubuntu or pluto ... or whatever you want)
16. save setting and reboot
17. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on boot and you will see a new entry (ubuntu or pluto or whatever you put on section 15)
18. Select that one and UBUNTU will boot strap correctly

I'm writing this guide using exactly my brand new Ubuntu on Acer Aspire One 756

If you  boot computer normally Windows 8 will boot !!

Answer (score 0):

On most computer there is a key you can press while booting to load a boot menu. In many systems it <kbd>F12</kbd> or some other function key.

On some other Acer's it is <kbd>F12</kbd> that brings up the boot menu. Give it a try.